# Pontryagin square and $\frac{1}{2}(\mathcal{P}(x) -x^2) =x \cup_1 Sq^1 x$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, group-cohomology, spectral-sequences, cobordism

The Pontryagin square, maps $x \in H^2({B}^2\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ to $ \mathcal{P}(x) \in H^4({B}^2\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_4)$. Precisely, 
$$
 \mathcal{P}(x)= x \cup x+ x \cup_1 2 Sq^1 x.
$$
The $\cup_1$ is a higher cup product. The $Sq^1 x=  x \cup_1 x$.
It shall be true that
$$
\mathcal{P}(x) \mod 2= x \cup x.
$$

> **Question 1**: 
>   If $ x \cup x =0 \mod 2$, and if $ x \cup_1 Sq^1 x =0 \mod 2$, is it true that
>   $$
> \mathcal{P}(x) =0 \mod 4?
> $$
>
> - If not, please provide some counter examples.

--

> **Question 2**: 
>   $\mathcal{P}(x)$ is a well-defined invariant for the cobordism $\Omega^4_{SO}(B^2 \mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_4$.
>   Is
>   $$
> \frac{1}{2}(\mathcal{P}(x) -x^2) \mod 2 = x \cup_1  Sq^1 x \mod 2
> $$
>   a well-defined invariant
>   of  the cobordism $\Omega^4_{Spin}(B^2 \mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2$?
>
> **Question 3**: Please provide the correct way to write the cobordism generator of $$\Omega^4_{Spin}(B^2 \mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2.$$

Comment: I meant Pontryagin square, maps $x \in H^2({B}^2\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ to $ \mathcal{P}(x) \in H^4({B}^2\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_4)$. Typo fixed

Comment: I'd like to get a little clarification because usually the cup-1 is only defined on the cochain level, and doesn't give an operation on cohomology groups, e.g. $x \cup_1 Sq^1 x$ usually doesn't have boundary zero. Are you asking about the cohomology level or the cochain level?

Comment: $x$ should be a cocycle defined above. It can be written as on a 2-simplex as the identity map $ x∈H^2(B^2ℤ_2,ℤ_2)$.

Comment: Then the full $P(x)=x∪x+x∪_12Sq^1x$ is also a 4-cocycle.

Comment: Other things I am not so sure -- so the comments answers from you are encouraged very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) No, not for any reasonable interpretation of your condition "$x \cup_1 Sq^1 x = 0$". Consider $M= S^2 \times S^2$, let $y \in H^2(M; \mathbb{Z})$ be the sum of the two obvious generators, and let $x \in H^2(M; \mathbb{Z}_2)$ be the mod 2 reduction of $y$. Then $P(x)$ is the mod 4 reduction of $y^2 = 2$, but certainly $x^2 = 0$ mod 2 and $Sq^1 x = 0$.

(2) No, I don't think either side of your equation is a well-defined element of $H^4(M; \mathbb{Z}_2)$ in general. Rather, Wu's theorem implies that if $M$ a closed spin 4-manifold and $x \in H^2(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ then
$x^2 = Sq^2x = w_2 x = 0$ (mod 2), so since the mod 2 reduction of $P(x)$ equals $x^2$ we get that $P(x) \in 2\mathbb{Z}_4$.
Hence $\frac12 P(x)$ can be interpreted as a well-defined homomorphism $\Omega_4^{Spin}(B^2\mathbb{Z}_2) \to \mathbb{Z}_2$.

(3) Taking $M = S^2 \times S^2$ and $x$ as in (1) shows that $\frac12 P(x)$ is non-trivial.

Comment: +1 Thanks, this is useful, but I like to have (3) written as precise 4d topological invariant term like $P(x)$ as for cobordism group generators. Thanks! What you wrote is for the bordism group generators, which is good but not enough

Comment: I think you mean it is $(1/2) P(x) $?

Comment: When you wrote " Wu's theorem implies that if $M$ a closed spin 4-manifold and $x \in H^2(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ then
$x^2 = Sq^2x = w_2 x = 0$," did you mean that $$x^2 = Sq^2x = w_2 x = 0 \mod 2$$ or mod 4?

Comment: I mean $x^2 = 0$ mod 2, so hence $P(x)$ is an even element of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ (I've made a clarifying edit).

Comment: Where can I find a introductory comprehensive proof on " Wu's theorem implies that if M a closed spin 4-manifold and x∈H2(M;ℤ2) then x2=Sq2x=w2x=0" ? thanks!

Comment: @annieheart In the following comment, I hope. Wu constructs, for a closed manifold $M$, characteristic classes $\nu_i \in H^i(M;\Bbb Z/2)$. These satisfy two properties: 1) for $x \in H^{n-i}(M;\Bbb Z/2)$, we have $\nu_i \cup x = \text{Sq}^i x$; 2) $w_k(M) = \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} \text{Sq}^i \nu_{k-i}$. Two axioms of Steenrod squares are that the operation $\text{Sq}^0 = 1$ and if $x \in H^k(M;\Bbb Z/2)$, then $\text{Sq}^k x = x^2$. Now $M$ is spin, so $w_1 = w_2 = 0$. Then (2) immediately implies that $\nu_1 = \nu_2 = 0$. Now $0 = \nu_2 \cup x = \text{Sq}^2 x = x^2$ as desired.